# How can I display 2 real-time value using SignalR in 2 elements ? (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I followed the video and I can display a real-time value using SignalR in  tag. But I don't know what signalr script code do so when I add a similar code to display 2 real-time values in 2 tags , it just displays one. I really hope someone will know clearly about that SignalR and please tell me something's wrong in my project? Thank you so much!

My code in index.html :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //Proxy created on the fly
        var cus = $.connection.cusHub;
        //Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke
        cus.client.displayValue = function () {
            getData();
            getData1();
        };
        
        //Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();
        getData1();
    });

    function getData() {
        var $tbl = $('#tblValue');
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#Get").val(),
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $tbl.empty();
                $.each(data.listCus, function (i, model) {
                    $tbl.append
                        (
                            model.Value
                        );
                });
            }
        });
    }
    function getData1() {
        var $tbl = $('#tblValue1');
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#Get1").val(),
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $tbl.empty();
                $.each(data.listCus1, function (i1, model) {
                    $tbl.append
                        (
                            model.Value
                        );
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Tag h2 with id="tblValue"> runs and has its value but not with id="tblValue1" :

```
                     <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="statistic__item statistic__item--orange">
                            <h2 id="tblValue" class="number">
                            </h2>
                            <span class="desc">MONTHLY COST</span>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="zmdi zmdi-money"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="statistic__item statistic__item--blue">
                            <h2 id="tblValue1" class="number">1,086</h2>
                            <span class="desc">YEARLY USAGE</span>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="zmdi zmdi-time"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My code in Controller ( I just copy paste from function JsonResult Get ) :

```
public JsonResult Get()
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ValueConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand value1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [DeviceID],[Value] FROM [dbo].[Device1] WHERE [DeviceID]='PM1'", connection))
                {
                    value1.Notification = null;

                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(value1);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    SqlDataReader reader = value1.ExecuteReader();

                    var listCus = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            DeviceID = (string)x["DeviceID"],
                            Value = (double)x["Value"],
                        }).ToList();
                    return Json(new { listCus = listCus }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

            }
        }
        public JsonResult Get1()
        {
            using (var connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ValueConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection1.Open();
                using (SqlCommand value1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [DeviceID],[Value] FROM [dbo].[Device1] WHERE [DeviceID]='PM2'", connection1))
                {
                    value1.Notification = null;

                    SqlDependency dependency1 = new SqlDependency(value1);
                    dependency1.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange1);

                    if (connection1.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection1.Open();

                    SqlDataReader reader1 = value1.ExecuteReader();

                    var listCus1 = reader1.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            DeviceID = (string)x["DeviceID"],
                            Value = (double)x["Value"],
                        }).ToList();
                    return Json(new { listCus1 = listCus1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

            }
        }

        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            CusHub.Show();
        }
        private void dependency_OnChange1(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            CusHub.Show();
        }
```

My code in CusHub.cs :

```
public class CusHub : Hub
    {
        public static void Show()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<CusHub>();
            context.Clients.All.displayValue();
        }
    }
```